# How to implement ASP.NET MVC button for saving an excel mapping on the fly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspose-cells

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I have an Excel template on the server which I used to generate a report. I want to give the user a functionality to change the name of the columns, which I know how to do using Aspose but I don't know how to do that without changing the original template. I want the user to be able to change any number of column names on the fly and use the new names for generating the report. I am not sure how to proceed. Should I save the mapping in the database and how this could be implemented in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

When Aspose.Cells loads your original template, it does not change it. For example, consider this code.

**C#**

```
//Load the template Excel file
Workbook wb = new Workbook("originalTemplate.xlsx");

//Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

//Access cell C4 and change its contents.
Cell c4 = ws.Cells["C4"];
c4.PutValue("This is a sample text.");

//Save the workbook
wb.Save("output.xlsx");
```

Once, this code executes, new file named output.xlsx will be created. Now open both originalTemplate.xlsx and output.xlsx in Microsoft Excel, you will see, there is no change in originalTemplate.xlsx and there is a change in output.xlsx where cell C4 has a text i.e. *"This is a sample text."*

**Conclusion:**
Aspose.Cells does not change the original template Excel file, all the changes are done inside the Workbook object in memory i.e. RAM and when user saves the Workbook object, it saves on disk as a new Excel file.

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose